# Which data structure in Java should I use for storing key value pairs in ordered form? No duplicates

Tags: java, data-structures, key-value

I am working on a project and I need to store key value pairs (one-to-one mapping) in an ordered fashion. Then I should be able to retrieve the key using the value and value using the key. I have looked at Maps, Sets and Hash Tables, but they aren't ordered.

Also, though trivial, it would be great if we could DS retrieve the keys and values at once i.e., the interface supports such functions.

EDIT: The keys and values are all unique. Maintaining the inserted order is good enough.

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` or `TreeMap` could help you.

Comment: You can sort a [BiMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236927/sorting-a-guava-dbimap) when needed.

Comment: Do you want order of "Order inserted" as a list, or "Natural order" where the collection "sorts itself" according to compareTo or a comparator?

Comment: You say you need to store in order. You say there is a one-to-one mapping. Any `Map` would store the data with one-to-one mapping. Why the ordering requirement? What do you need to do in order?

Comment: I need the ordering to save the values into a database table...

Comment: @RoshanSubudhi - storing values in a DB table is a fairly common problem, and generally people don't need to resort to an Ordered Bi-directional Map in order to implement that.  It's possible you are over-engineering your solution.  Maybe the DB can (or should) handle data in any order.  Maybe you could build the map, get the set of keys and sort them (as a list) and iterate over the sorted list.  You know your project best, but whenever you run into a problem no one else has solved before, it's often an indication that you're thinking about it too hard.

Comment: Actually, @dimo414, now that I have started to incorporate the code I got via this post, I am in total consent with you. I have often been told so by my professor too!

Comment: @RoshanSubudhi: Which data structure u choosed finally? just curious to know.

Comment: @VishalK... After considering the discussion in this thread (especially the one of over-engineering my solution), I got suspicious that no one had this issue so far... So, I re-designed my code so that I did not have to use any collection... a simple 2-D  Array helped me out finally... but, I learnt a lot from this thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you don't define what counts as "ordered".  A [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) enables iterating over the keys (and therefore values) in insertion-order.  Conversely, a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) lets you specify a sort order with a comparator, and ensures all items added to the map are stored in sorted order.  99 times out of 100, one of these classes should be all you need.  Alternatively, Google's [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) project has several very nice [BiMap](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap) implementations that you may find fits your needs.

**I strongly caution you: if you think you need more than what these classes can provide, you are likely over-engineering your problem.**

---

For reasons I can't fully justify, I implemented a proper `UniqueOrderedBiMap` for you, which is compatible with the Java Collections framework and all implemented functions run efficiently.  You can use whatever underlying map you see fit (including an un-ordered map, if you really wanted) and keys and values are always unique.  Notice that it is a *very* thin wrapper around a `LinkedHashMap`, because that's all you need, a `LinkedHashMap` with extra checks to ensure Values remain unique.

For the curious, check this answers revision history for a `UniqueOrderedMap` which lacks the `getKey()` and `removeKey()` methods, but more properly implements the `Map` interface, and only needs a HashSet, rather than a HashMap, to store the known values.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class UniqueOrderedBiMap<K, V>implements Map<K, V> {
    private Map<K, V> orderedMap;
    private HashMap<V, K> valueMap;

    public UniqueOrderedBiMap() {
        this(new LinkedHashMap<K,V>());
    }

    public UniqueOrderedBiMap(Map<K, V> underlyingMap) {
        orderedMap = underlyingMap;
        valueMap = new HashMap<V, K>(orderedMap.size());

        for(Map.Entry<K, V> e : orderedMap.entrySet()) {
            if(!valueMap.containsKey(e.getValue())) { // Duplicate value
                // could instead fail softly by removing the associated item from the map, but this seems cleaner/clearer.
                // generally this constructor should be passed an empty map anyways
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate value "+e.getValue()+" found in underlying map.");
            }
            valueMap.put(e.getValue(), e.getKey());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return orderedMap.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return orderedMap.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return orderedMap.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        // more efficient than iterating over the map
        return valueMap.containsKey(value);
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return orderedMap.get(key);
    }

    public K getKey(V value) {
        return valueMap.get(value);
    }

    // Likely want to implement a forcePut(K, V) method like Guava's BiMaps do
    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if(valueMap.containsKey(value)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot insert non-unique value "+value);
        }
        V ret = orderedMap.put(key, value);
        valueMap.remove(ret);
        valueMap.put(value, key);
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        V ret = orderedMap.remove(key);
        valueMap.remove(ret);
        return ret;
    }

    public K removeKey(V value) {
        K ret = valueMap.remove(value);
        orderedMap.remove(ret);
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        // Existing Map implementation's putAll have some optimizations we
        // could take advantage of, but this isn't unreasonable for a first pass
        for(Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e : m.entrySet()) {
            put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        orderedMap.clear();
        valueMap.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return orderedMap.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        return orderedMap.values();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return orderedMap.entrySet();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof UniqueOrderedBiMap) {
            UniqueOrderedBiMap<?,?> map = (UniqueOrderedBiMap<?,?>)o;
            return orderedMap.equals(map.orderedMap); 
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return orderedMap.hashCode();
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return orderedMap.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = { "Marcus", "Jim", "Tom", "Sam" };
        String[] grades = { "A", "B", "D", "F" };

        UniqueOrderedBiMap<String,String> insertionMap = new UniqueOrderedBiMap<>();
        UniqueOrderedBiMap<String,String> sortedMap = new UniqueOrderedBiMap<>(new TreeMap<String,String>());

        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            insertionMap.put(names[i], grades[i]);
            sortedMap.put(names[i], grades[i]);
        }

        // Poor man's assert
        System.out.println(insertionMap.toString().equals("{Marcus=A, Jim=B, Tom=D, Sam=F}"));
        System.out.println(sortedMap.toString().equals("{Jim=B, Marcus=A, Sam=F, Tom=D}"));

        insertionMap.put("Tom", "C");
        sortedMap.put("Tom", "C");
        System.out.println(insertionMap.toString().equals("{Marcus=A, Jim=B, Tom=C, Sam=F}"));
        System.out.println(sortedMap.toString().equals("{Jim=B, Marcus=A, Sam=F, Tom=C}"));

        try {
            insertionMap.put("Sam", "C");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            sortedMap.put("Sam", "C");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        insertionMap.remove("Tom");
        sortedMap.remove("Tom");
        insertionMap.put("Sam", "C");
        sortedMap.put("Sam", "C");
        System.out.println(insertionMap.toString().equals("{Marcus=A, Jim=B, Sam=C}"));
        System.out.println(sortedMap.toString().equals("{Jim=B, Marcus=A, Sam=C}"));

        insertionMap.removeKey("A");
        sortedMap.removeKey("A");
        System.out.println(insertionMap.toString().equals("{Jim=B, Sam=C}"));
        System.out.println(sortedMap.toString().equals("{Jim=B, Sam=C}"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry But I could not find method where key could be retrieved using value. Also I could not find the method where `key-value` pair is removed on the basis of input value.

Comment: That's true, this is a Unique Ordered Map, which implements the Map interface with the expectations of ordering and unique values.  I will update with a UniqueOrderedBiMap class that enables `K get(V)` and `K remove(V)`.  As I said in a comment on the question itself, it's likely such a data structure is over-engineering, and not practically necessary, but it's simple enough to implement if that's really what you want.

Comment: If someone has to keep the `insertion order` then what is the need of all these engineering of new class? He/She could simply use `LinkedHashMap` . And as far as point of keeping the value as unique, before putting `key-value` in the map he could simply check the existence of `value` using `containsValue(Object value) `. If it returns true and exception would be generated as `key-value` pair would be successfully put .

Comment: Like I said, if you think you really need an UniqueOrderedBiMap you're almost certainly over-engineering the problem.  A LinkedHashMap or a TreeMap provide ordered iteration over a map, which is all one should almost ever need.  The above implementation does what OP asked for efficiently and cleanly (the latter being the primary reason to create a new class), but it's not necessarily a good thing to want in the first place.

Comment: But still it doesn't fulfill the most dominant need of OP . i.e search and remove my `value`. I am really curious to know how this could be achieved using the `Map` as I had already gave a lot of thought on this , but i could not get any way or clue.

Comment: Quite simply, see my `getKey()` and `removeKey()` methods, along with the test in the main method.

Comment: That absolutely solves the problem . But don't you think that making two copies of each 'key-value` pair in two separate maps is leading to data redundancy? if we have `n` `key-value` pair then we would have `2*n` `key-value` pairs in memory ?

Comment: Like with many things, we're trading off memory, speed, and engineering time.  One alternative would be to take the raw code in HashMap and implement a raw bi-hash structure, however that's far more error prone and complex.  This implementation does indeed use two maps, but the point of keeping them private is to prevent data-inconsistency (from the user's perspective, there's only one map) and ensure speed.  In general, if you want a data structure with this much complexity, you're going to just accept the memory overhead, there's no other way around it.  O(n) get time is just unacceptable.

Comment: You were very true in what you said. Yes `ArrayList` is bad choice for such work. I have tested both the solutions and found that the `HashMaps` are the best choice and works efficiently at the cost of little extra memory. I consider your solution as accepted. Thanks for pointing out all necessary points and Taking your time to continue the conversations. As a matter of fact I would like to delete my accepted Answer as it would be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use third party libraries then consider using an [`ImmutableBiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/ImmutableBiMap.html). Its a Guava Collection class that provides

1. User specified iteration order
2. Normal mapping from keys to values and inverse mapping from values to keys

The one consideration is that once created the map is immutable and cannot be modified.

Comment: Or even the mutable [HashBiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html)

Comment: @dimo414 - yes, he can store the core data in a HashBiMap then convert it into an ImmutableBiMap when the sorting is needed.

Comment: Sorry, brain-fart; forgot HashBiMap isn't Linked

Comment: I would consider third party libraries as a last resort, since I would have to come up to speed to use them.

Comment: Guava is an incredibly powerful and easy to use library.  While not part of the standard JDK, any Java project that doesn't add Guava to it's classpath as a very first step is missing out on lots of excellent tools, and reinventing dozens of wheels needlessly.  Instead of thinking of Guava as a third party library, think of it as a standard library you just need to include explicitly.

Comment: Ok. Downloading it... :)

Answer (score 0):

[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) should be suitable for you. Read through the link

Answer (score 0):

You will need two `LinkedHashMap`. You can create custom class that internally uses two `LinkedHashMap`. One for mapping keys to value and another one for mapping values to key.

Comment: It's more commonly called a multimap.  There's no such thing built into the Java collections, but the Google collections have an implementation of it.

Comment: A multimap is a map of lists, not the same as a two-directional map, which Shivam is suggesting.  Only one of the maps actually needs to be a LinkedHashMap, however.

Comment: Dont we have something like a LinkedhashTable? LinkedhashMap sounds good but maintaining two Maps does not seem appealing.

Comment: @dimo414 True. You would require only one of them to be `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: How would I use only one `LikedHashMap`. I use `get` for obtaining a value using a key. What about vice versa?

Comment: You have one "primary" map which tracks keys to values and the ordering, then a secondary "reverse" map that maps values to keys.  Since you'll only ever iterate over the primary map, there's no need to take up the extra space/time to force the reverse map to be ordered.